# JavaFx Answer to EDT?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I asked  a question  about using threads in GUI and got the following response:

> You have to rework your program.
>
> 1. GUI elements should be updated from within the GUI thread (EDT)
>      only, not from a standalone thread.
> 2. Client connection should be divided in 2 weakly connected parts:
>      sending messages and receiving them. Receiving should be a separate
>      thread, and sending can be a thread or a class.
> 3. When the receiving thread have read a message, it sends it to EDT
>      using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable). Examples can be found
>      elsewhere.
> 4. When user have entered text, the text is send to the socket
>      directly, or enqueued in a queue and later processed by the sending
>      thread, if any.

What i want to know is what is the JavaFx response to EDT and could anyone give an example of how to use it?

My first post can be found at this link [Server / client program stops working after Thread starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872918/server-client-program-stops-working-after-thread-starts)

- Note if it matters I've build my GUI in javaFx Scene builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I just override the run method of **Task** to keep the cores busy and to get the job done. Non-visual tasks are done by extending the Service class. The JavaFX application thread is used exclusively to invoke all the methods and state on the **Service**.

> A Service is a non-visual component encapsulating the information
>   required to perform some work on one or more background threads.
>
> Task is a fully observable implementation of a FutureTask. Tasks
>   exposes additional state and observable properties useful for
>   programming asynchronous tasks in JavaFX, as defined in the Worker
>   interface.

Non-UI calculations like sending messages should happen in a separate thread by running a task. You can change the UI (display the msg) when messages are received by using `Platform.runLater(java.lang.Runnable runnable)` from the JavaFX Application thread(same as EDT) but it can make the UI laggy, so it is preferred to do intensive stuff from separate threads.

So, you can define a task and trigger the new thread by calling `new Thread(task).start();`. In your Task anonymous class, you can add a listener that updates the UI when a message is received. A task can have the following [WorkerStateEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/WorkerStateEvent.html#field_summary)s and you can listen in on them.

Sample code of using Task from http://fxexperience.com/2011/07/worker-threading-in-javafx-2-0/ and using stateProperty listener.

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void run() {
        static final int max = 1000000;
        for (int i=1; i<=max; i++) {
            updateProgress(i, max);
        }
        return null;
    }
};
ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
new Thread(task).start();
```

---

```
task.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> observable,
                State oldValue, Worker.State newState) {
            if(newState==Worker.State.SUCCEEDED){
                //doSomething()
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: How will i know when to run the task? I am currently creating a task program and i only need to Update the gui when something happens with 1 or more chat person for example chat text or if a new person connects to the chat

Comment: and by task program i mean chat program (sorry mistyped).

Comment: Okay just let me get this straight! I create a new class called client listner that extends thread i then create a task in my gui controllere and pass it as a parameter to my thread?? Or ho does it work?

Comment: I used the Smack API for messaging and building Hyperbola in Eclipse. In your controller, establish connection, define an anonymous class for Task, override its run method by adding PacketListener code like this -     `if (connection != null) {
PacketListener listener = new PacketListener() {
public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
Message message = (Message) packet;
if (message.getType() == Message.Type.chat)
startChat(message);
}
};
PacketFilter filter = new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class);
connection.addPacketListener(listener, filter);
}` and call `new Thread(task).start();`.

Comment: I am really glad for your response :) and thank you for all your help. Can i ask you for some help over skype? just so i know that i am on the right track? :) would help me alot!

Comment: LOL, found over 35 Marc Rasmussen accounts in Skype. My skype id is acedude0101.

Comment: Thank you mate :) i will add you :D

Comment: ive added you i am NemeoDizzy

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the corresponding SwingUtil.invokeLater in JavaFX. If yes, it is 
    Platform.runLater(java.lang.Runnable runnable)

Quote from the API http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html

> Run the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at some
>   unspecified time in the future.